# How to make youtube embed code HTML valid for w3c validator?

Tags: html, youtube, w3c, w3c-validation

Here is my code.

```
<div>
    <object>
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cbspv1ZKR8o?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param value="transparent" name="wmode" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cbspv1ZKR8o?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" class="cssVideo"></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

But the above code failed to pass the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/).
I search and try to follow [these](https://www.worthapost.com/404.html) [guides](http://xahlee.info/js/html_embed_video.html) but I am unable to solve the problem.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to always use the embeded code provided from youtube.

Below is a typical way to change the embedded version of the `youtube` and validate it as well.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/n">
     <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/n" />
     <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="blank"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get flash player to play to this file" width="88" height="31" /></a><br />
</object>
```

Where `n` is the `youtube` id of the video.

See a demo [validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FgqWKd%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Cheers Prabhu :)

Answer (score 4):

If you re-read the articles you posted, you will see that their correct versions do not use an `embed` object (*which is deprecated in xhtml-1.0*).

Use

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cbspv1ZKR8o?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" width="480" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cbspv1ZKR8o?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object>
```

[*Working Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/JkgRr/)  and 
[*Validation*](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fgaby%2FJkgRr%2Fshow%2Flight%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0):

this problem I have solved via the code below and it will be worked.

```
                        <!----------Vimo vedio---------->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://player.vimeo.com/video/355186746" width="480" height="360">
                        <param name="movie" value="https://player.vimeo.com/video/355186746" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param value="transparent" name="wmode" />
                        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                        <embed src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/355186746" width="640" height="361" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture">
                    </object>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it solve the issue